# HP Fortify flags a privacy violation critical error when writing an id to archive

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc, archive, fortify

```
void SampleBaseClass::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    // Serialize base class data first
    CObject::Serialize(ar);

    // Serialize my data now
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        ar << m_sPersonIdentificationNumber; //Flags the critical issue here
    }
    else
    {
     ......
    }
}
```

Here's the declaration of the SampleBaseClass

```
class SampleBaseClass : public CObject
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(SampleBaseClass)
// Constructors / Destructor
public:
    SampleBaseClass();
    SampleBaseClass(const SampleBaseClass& cpy);
    SampleBaseClass& operator =(const SampleBaseClass& cpy);
    virtual ~SampleBaseClass();

// Attributes
public:
    double                      m_dPersonId;
    CString                     m_sPersonIdentificationNumber;


// Operations
public: 
    virtual void Serialize(CArchive& ar);

protected:
    void Copy(const SampleBaseClass& cpy);
};
```

Also, I have the "<<" operator overloaded. Below is the overloaded function

```
    template< typename BaseType, class StringTraits >
CArchive& CArchive::operator<<(const ATL::CStringT<BaseType, StringTraits>& str)
{
    AfxWriteStringLength(*this, str.GetLength(), sizeof(BaseType) == sizeof(wchar_t));
    Write(str, str.GetLength()*sizeof(BaseType));
    return *this;
}
```

How do I fix this issue without having to alter the design significantly?

Comment: Show the declaration of `SampleBaseClass` or at least the relevant parts of it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Please refer the edit

Comment: Show also the  code for the overloaded "<<" operator .

Comment: @MichaelWalz Added that too.

Comment: Does the `operator<<` behave correctly with null/empty strings?

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes, it does.

Comment: @DouglasHeld Any inputs?